# Angular - Change button style on click of dynamic list of buttons

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to make dynamic list of buttons when ever click on 1 button, it's style should be change, I'm not getting idea to how to make this work
for example:
[image]

when ever we click on one of the these button only that button style changes. any idea how to make this work?
plus here is a [link](https://myshop-7a60b.web.app/home) who is using similar work still not getting idea.

Comment: You can do it with `:active` pseudo class. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active).

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example? You can use ngClass to add classes dynamically.

Comment: @KhizarMurad, check out my solution.

Comment: I believe the [button toggle component](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview) is what you're looking for. (Additionally, is your question asking about AngularJS or Angular? The two frameworks aren't exactly the same..)

Comment: @Edric no I don't to do with toggle component, I believe Zunayed resolved my issue. and Sorry it was just angular question.

Comment: @Rajat yes I wasn't getting the idea but zunayed resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want fully dynamic then create an array of button names.

```
buttons = ['Button 1', 'Button 2', 'Button 3'];
```

And a variable for the selected button and assign the first button as selected.

```
selectedButton: string = this.buttons[0];
```

Create a function to check the selected button.

```
isButtonSelected(button: string) {
    return button === this.selectedButton;
}
```

Add `switchButton` function to toggle your selection.

```
switchButton(button: string) {
   this.selectedButton = button;
}
```

Iterate your buttons at HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let button of buttons">
    <button mat-button [ngClass]="{'mat-raised-button':isButtonSelected(button)}" (click)="switchButton(button)">{{button}}</button>
</ng-container>
```

You can now change `mat-raised-button` to any other button type as your wish.

**See detail in working demo** at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7f7vzq-frka8l?file=src/app/button-overview-example.html).